# Instagram Subscribe

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Is there any way how can I subscribe / unsubscribe programatically on **Instagram**, if I have the account credentials? There are plenty of Websites, which are doing the same. But, as far as I know, there is no API, which makes that possible.

Comment: Private API, find it on GitHub/

Comment: @AdamAzad thanks for the answer! I've tried out instagram4j library with Spring Boot, having 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'okhttp3.RequestBody okhttp3.RequestBody.create(java.lang.String, okhttp3.MediaType)'' exception. Do you know what it can be?

Comment: To be frank, I know there are libraries to use the private API, but haven't any myself. You can try to file an issue on GitHub's repo and take it from there. Good luck!